# Changing size of Java button GridBayLayout

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout

Hello I have a big problem. I would like to make "=" button 2*height and the "0" button 2*width(OTHER buttons should be just normal size), that's all I tried many combinantions, but instead i get weird sizes.

O i get that

[what i get http://desmond.imageshack.us/Himg684/scaled.php?server=684&filename=33109545.jpg&res=landing](http://desmond.imageshack.us/Himg684/scaled.php?server=684&filename=33109545.jpg&res=landing)

I would like to get sth similar to that I found in web(only button layout)

[image]

```
public void someMethod()
    Container cp = getContentPane();
    cp.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    JPanel wyswietlacz = new JPanel();
    JTextField txt = new JTextField("123");
    txt.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(getWidth() - 10, 35));
    txt.setAlignmentX(JTextField.RIGHT_ALIGNMENT);
    wyswietlacz.add(txt);
    JPanel opcje = new JPanel();
    String[] etykiety = { "C", ".", "/", "*", "7", "8", "9", "-", "4", "5",
            "6", "+", "1", "2", "3", "=", "0", "+/-" };

    JButton[] przyciski = new JButton[18];
    for (int i = 0; i < przyciski.length; i++)
        przyciski[i] = new JButton(etykiety[i]);

    GridBagLayout gridbag = new GridBagLayout();
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    opcje.setLayout(gridbag);
    for (int i = 0; i < przyciski.length; i++) {
        if (((i + 1) % 4) == 0) {

            c.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        } else {
            c.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.RELATIVE;

        }

        if (i == 15) {
            c.gridheight = 2;

            c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        }
        if (i == 16)
            c.gridy = GridBagConstraints.SOUTH;

        if (i == 16) {
            c.gridwidth = 2;
            c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        }

        makebutton(przyciski[i], gridbag, c, opcje);
    }

    add(wyswietlacz, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add(opcje, BorderLayout.CENTER);

}

protected void makebutton(JButton button, GridBagLayout gridbag,
        GridBagConstraints c, JPanel jp) {
    gridbag.setConstraints(button, c);
    jp.add(button);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Kalkulator();
}
```

Comment: Just please make sure that `someMethod()` isn't the paint method!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try your hands on this code example and ask any questions that may arise :

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class GridBagTest
{
    private String[] buttonText = { "C", ".", "/", "*", "7", "8", "9", "-", "4", "5",
            "6", "+", "1", "2", "3", "=", "0", "+/-" };
    private JButton[] button = new JButton[18];
    private int counter = 0;

    private void createAndDisplayGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("GridBagLayout Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JPanel northPanel = new JPanel();
        northPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout(2, 2));
        JTextField tfield = new JTextField();
        northPanel.add(tfield, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel();
        centerPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_START;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.weightx = 1.0;
        gbc.weighty = 1.0;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2);
        for (int i = 0; i < button.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Button Text : " + buttonText[i]);
            button[i] = new JButton(buttonText[i]);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            {
                    gbc.gridx = j;
                    gbc.gridy = i;
                    centerPanel.add(button[counter++], gbc);
            }
        }
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 3;
        centerPanel.add(button[counter++], gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 3;
        centerPanel.add(button[counter++], gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 2;
        gbc.gridy = 3;
        centerPanel.add(button[counter++], gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 3;
        gbc.gridy = 3;  
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc.gridheight = 2;
        centerPanel.add(button[counter++], gbc);
        int count = counter;
        System.out.println(button[--count].getText());
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 4;
        gbc.gridheight = 1;
        gbc.gridwidth = 2;
        centerPanel.add(button[counter++], gbc);
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc.gridx = 2;
        gbc.gridy = 4;
        centerPanel.add(button[counter++], gbc);

        contentPane.add(northPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        contentPane.add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                new GridBagTest().createAndDisplayGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here is the output :

[image: CALCULATOR]

Comment: @RobertKilar : You're MOST WELCOME and KEEP SMILING :-)

Comment: A fancy GridBagLayout example it is too. 1+

Answer (score 6):

I can't see any issue with that, please read

- [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html)
- [GridBagConstraints and anchor too](http://java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/1480__GridBagConstraints.htm)

then

[image]

from code

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class GridBagButtons {

    private static final Insets insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);

    public static void main(final String args[]) {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("GridBagLayout");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        JButton button;
        // Row One - Three Buttons
        button = new JButton("One");
        addComponent(frame, button, 0, 0, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.BOTH);
        button = new JButton("Two");
        addComponent(frame, button, 1, 0, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.BOTH);
        button = new JButton("Three");
        addComponent(frame, button, 2, 0, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.BOTH);
        // Row Two - Two Buttons
        button = new JButton("Four");
        addComponent(frame, button, 0, 1, 2, 1, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.BOTH);
        button = new JButton("Five");
        addComponent(frame, button, 2, 1, 1, 2, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.BOTH);
        // Row Three - Two Buttons
        button = new JButton("Six");
        addComponent(frame, button, 0, 2, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.BOTH);
        button = new JButton("Seven");
        addComponent(frame, button, 1, 2, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.BOTH);
        frame.setSize(500, 200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static void addComponent(Container container, Component component, int gridx, int gridy,
            int gridwidth, int gridheight, int anchor, int fill) {
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints(gridx, gridy, gridwidth, gridheight, 1.0, 1.0,
                anchor, fill, insets, 0, 0);
        container.add(component, gbc);
    }

    private GridBagButtons() {
    }
}
```

- I'd be use NestedLayout rather than bothering with GrigBagLayout, SpringLayout or MigLayout

Comment: Thank you I corrected code:
http://wklej.org/id/753239/but I get sth like that
![](http://desmond.imageshack.us/Himg207/scaled.php?server=207&filename=25202449.jpg&res=landing)

Comment: maybe custom MigLayout is better and easiest, sorry but I don't know something about their licencing,

Comment: Any idea with this GridBag : ( from default library?

Comment: @Robert Kilar please I don't know why, sorry I sent you full specifications how GridBagLayout works inc code example, I don't want to debug your code, no reason for that, hmmmm we aren't any type of codding support here, on this forum we can send you proper and show you correct direction(s),

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you don't set weightx and weighty on the GridBagConstraints. Setting them to 1.0 will allocate the (horizontal/vertical) extra space to each component equally.

Comment: http://wklej.org/id/753244/ 
thanks,
now it works but only if I use correct window size, otherwise last row will fit window.

Comment: @RobertKilar what do you mean too wide?

Comment: http://desmond.imageshack.us/Himg191/scaled.php?server=191&filename=72720252.jpg&res=landing

the left is size 500,300 of the JFrame and the right is 180,208

Comment: @RobertKilar It looks like you are setting weightx/weighty only for some buttons. I understood that you wanted the buttons to fill the entire area.